# Object-safe move element from the end of a vector to the end of another vector

Tags: c++, stl, move

I'm very new in C++.

I investigated a lot of articles about C++ and solution for moving vector's last element to another but I still don't understand how to do that.

I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<Person *> persons;
std::vector<Person *> availablePersons;
```

and function:

```
MoveLast() {
    std::move(persons.end() - 1, persons.end(), std::back_inserter(availablePersons));
}
```

But it looks very long and doesn't work as expected.

So I need simple and effective method without losing `Person` objects in the memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors don't contain `Person` objects, they just contain pointers. Moving these pointers really means performing a copy. So you're doing two things, copying a pointer to one container and removing a pointer from another container. A simple implementation like this should be all you need:

```
MoveLast() {
    if (!persons.empty()) { // ensure source vector isn't empty
        availablePersons.push_back(persons.back()); // copy last element to destination
        persons.pop_back(); // remove last element from source
    }
}
```

If your vectors held a type that was move-enabled then, as an optimization, you might change the second line to this:

```
availablePersons.push_back(std::move(persons.back())); // move last element to destination
```

Comment: But I have SIGILL issue in range-based loop on `availablePersons` later.. I thought it's related to how I create this vector

Comment: @featureoffuture That problem must be due to some other code not shown. Using raw pointers might be part of the problem if they're NULL or pointing to invalid objects. Typically iterating over a container doesn't cause a fault. The `MoveLast()` function I posted performs fairly simple operations that also shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yes. You're right. Just figured I didn't return result from some function at the code... But there was no compile error or warning for some reason. Thanks anyway! You helped a lot!